# Sum two std::array of non-default-constructible types

Tags: c++, std

If I want to write a function summing two `std::array`, I would do something like:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto sum(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
{
    std::array< decltype(a[0] + b[0]), N> result; //the underlying type is not necessarily T
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

How would I write this function in case `decltype(a[0] + b[0])` is not default-constructible?

Here is an example on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/qndGfhehM

Ideally, I want to directly create and initialize the `std::array`, but I failed to write a function for any `N`.

I would like to rely only on a C++ standard.

I guess the implementation can be achieved with an intermediate `std::vector`, but it would require copies.

I tried to write a recursive template function such as:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto operator+(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
{
    if constexpr (N > 1)
    {
        return {a[0] + b[0], ???};
    }
    else
    {
        return {a[0] + b[0]};
    }
}
```

but I don't know what to write instead of the *???*.

I am aware that `std::index_sequence` exists, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: `index_sequence` tricks are clever, but if you need to use them, it's a sign of a design issue. It's rarely a good idea to not have a default constructor.

Comment: A std::array is "an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member."
Since `SumA` is not default constructable, `SumA arr[N]` is not either.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Not all type would have correct default values. Initialization is better than assignation IMO, I don't see any design issue for that in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto sum_helper(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b,
                std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(a[0] + b[0]), N>{(a[Is] + b[Is])...};
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto sum(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
{
    return sum_helper(a, b, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cch5KGKc4)

Comment: Your solution works, thanks. Pack expansion is a part of C++ that I never experienced, I [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) does not give a lot of details...

Comment: I wondered if this solution is more efficient than the naive implementation, so I made a [quick bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/T1eTdkWEXRR3Iu05Ct-yN4vATFw). It is a bit faster for small arrays, but becomes more and more significant as the size of the arrays grows.

Comment: I suggest marking the helper `static`.

Answer (score 12):

Using `std::index_sequence` is a two-step process:

Create it and pass it to a helper which uses the indices for your task.
A generic lambda with explicit template-arguments is enough for that (for earlier standards, use a normal function and more arguments):

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
auto operator+(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<decltype(a[0] + b[0]), N>{(a[Is] + b[Is])...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: I guess you could write just `return std::array{(a[Is] + b[Is])...};`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, but OP's code already relies on C++20 anyway.

Comment: @Evg You're right, my response should have addressed your comment under that other answer. But you've removed it already :)

Comment: @Evg The devil is in the details. For `N==0`, that would not actually do.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the case where `decltype(a[0] + b[0])` is not default-constructible, you can use a helper function along with `std::index_sequence` to create and initialize the `std::array`. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// Helper function to initialize the array recursively
template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto sum_helper(const std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>& a, const std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>& b, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>{(a[Is] + b[Is])...};
}

// Main function that calls the helper with an index sequence
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto sum(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b)
{
    return sum_helper(a, b, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> arr1{1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 3> arr2{4, 5, 6};

    auto result = sum(arr1, arr2);

    for (const auto& elem : result)
    {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`sum_helper` is a recursive function that takes two arrays (`a` and `b`) and an `index_sequence` representing the indices. It recursively initializes the elements of the result array using the expression `(a[Is] + b[Is])...`.

The `sum` function then calls this helper function with `std::make_index_sequence<N>()`, which generates an index sequence for the given array size N. This way, you can handle non-default-constructible types without resorting to an intermediate `std::vector` or other containers.